Issue with data sync between Box com and SharepointOnline
Good day to all,
I wanted to use Power Automate to synchronize files between Box.com and Sharepoint Online.
I have created a flow which checks the files from Box.com as soon as they are created and transfers them to Sharepoint.
However, it only works to a limited extent, as the files are transferred, but can no longer be opened afterwards (via Sharepoint Online browser or desktop), as the files are corrupt and only 1B in size.
The flow looks like this:
Trigger:

(BOX) When a file is created (properties only) V2

Next Step:

(Sharepoint) Create File (Sharepoint)
Site Address: Address of the site
Folder Path: Target folder
File name: DisplayName (dynamic content)
File content: Media Type

Has anyone already had to map this or a similar scenario?
Thanks a lot.
I tried different actions and search on Google, but still not resolving my issue.

how do you get the file content from the box.com file? You say file content = media type. That doesn't make any sense. If you create a file in SharePoint, you need to get the content first as a binary object.

Thanks for your response.
You are right but i dont know how to realize this in Power Automate.
I find the following functions
binary(value)
dataUriToBinary(Value)
uriComponentToBinary(value)
base64ToBinary(value)
decodeDataUri(value)
My idea was to check if a file is uploaded and transfer the new file to Sharepoint Online. I thought it was possible using power automate.

Trigger: (BOX) When a file is created (properties only) V2 - will return the List of File property array
using that property (id) from a trigger, need to download that file content
Action: (BOX) Get file content using id
Previous action content should be saved in Sharepoint
Below sample fetch file content from Box and send it to mail
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65f5iMoB.png

Thanks for you response.
I'll try it later and let you know.
